# Выбрать элементы по массиву со списком ключей

Tags: php

Есть ли какая-нибудь функция в `php`, позволяющая выбрать из одного массива элементы, ключи которых соответствуют элементам другого массива? Вот пример:

```
$arr = [
    'key1' => 'elem1',
    'key2' => 'elem2',
    'key3' => 'elem3'
];

$keys = [
    0 => 'key1',
    1 => 'key3',
];

$result = [
    'key1' => 'elem1',
    'key3' => 'elem3'
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант

```
$result = array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip($keys));
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [функции пересечения массивов](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-uintersect-uassoc.php), например:

```
$result = array_uintersect_uassoc(
    $arr,
    $keys,
    function($a,$b){return 0;},
    function($a,$b)use($keys){return in_array($a, $keys) ? 0 : 1;}
);
```